# Error while importing BlackBerry project in Eclipse - BlackBerry JRE 4.7.0[unbound]

Tags: blackberry, java, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am new in BlackBerry application development. I have installed "BlackBerry Plug-ins for Eclipse version 7.1" successfully.  Now I am trying to import one existing project into Eclipse, it is showing the following error:

> Build path entry is missing: org.eclipse.jdt.lau...de.BlackBerryVMInstallType/BlackBerry JRE 4.7.0

[image]

what is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you tell us if the project you are importing was originally built in Eclipse or JDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have **only** installed the OS 7.1 plugin, then you won't be able to target OS 4.7.

You'll need to also install the SDK for OS 4.7.  To do that, in Eclipse, go to the **Help** menu, then **Install New Software...**, then select the **Work With:** pull-down menu, and pick the [BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin site](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java).

Then, in the center of the window, you'll select the SDKs (OS Versions) you want to directly target:

[image]

As you see, I'm using the Mac Eclipse Plugin, and it doesn't even show OS 4.7 ... I can't remember if the Windows versions still supports 4.7 (I think it might offer a 4.5 plugin).  Basically, all the 4.7 devices out there should be eligible for free upgrades to 5.0, so I don't know that it's worth it to support 4.7 anymore.  Just support OS 5.0+.

Once you're sure that you **have** the correct SDK, then in the window you show in your screenshot, try removing that OS 4.7 library.  Then, use the **Add Library..** button, select **JRE System Library** and pick the **BlackBerry JRE 5.0.0** (it may be in the **Alternate JRE** menu):

[image]

After you do that, try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: There is no 4.7 JRE for Windows either.